# Ignoring an error when working with google maps inexisting data

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get some information about the distances and duration of some itineraries from the google maps api. The problem is im trying ti find this itineraries from a certain city to a bunch of other, where in some cases there is no existing road. In that case, google maps says their are no results. Thats ok, but Im new to python so i dont now how to ignore this error an keep calculating the rest of itineraries.

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='API_KEY')

Indice_Ciudad=0

 input=open(r'C:\Users\SantiagoCC\Desktop\destinos.csv','r')
 output=open(r'C:\Users\SantiagoCC\Desktop\Distancias_a_Corabastos.csv','w')

try:
reader=csv.reader(input)
writer=csv.writer(output)
for row in list(reader)[1:]:
    ciudad=row[Indice_Ciudad]
    print(ciudad)

    distancias=gmaps.distance_matrix((4.630562, -74.159983), ciudad)

    writer.writerow((ciudad,
      distancias['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'],
      distancias['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value'], ))
```

When an itineraire doesnt exist, it just says KeyError 'distance'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could catch the exception and deal with it accordingly. Note that this will however include other keyerrors (not just on the distance field).

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='API_KEY')

Indice_Ciudad=0

input=open(r'C:\Users\SantiagoCC\Desktop\destinos.csv','r')
output=open(r'C:\Users\SantiagoCC\Desktop\Distancias_a_Corabastos.csv','w')

reader=csv.reader(input)
writer=csv.writer(output)
for row in list(reader)[1:]:

    try:
        ciudad=row[Indice_Ciudad]
        print(ciudad)

        distancias=gmaps.distance_matrix((4.630562, -74.159983), ciudad)

        writer.writerow((ciudad,
          distancias['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'],
          distancias['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value'], ))

    except KeyError, e:
        print "Some data is missing from row {}, got {}".format(row, e)
        pass # Move on to next row
```

Comment: Thanks, @bouletta
Do I have to literally code

       except KeyError, e:

????
When I do, i get a Syntax error, python doesnt understand the comma, or e:

Comment: why version of python are you using?
try replacing it by `KeyError as e:`.
You can also just put `KeyError:` having 'e' here is just if you want to print the actual error in case of an exception.

Comment: Im using Python 3.6, that part works now, but it doesnt understand the next part,     

        print "Some data is missing from row {}, got {}".format(row, e)

It says there is a Syntax error on the second ", just before . format(row,e)

Comment: I only use Python 2.7 and it works for me. I'm sorry I don't know how to format string with Python 3.6. I was aware `except KeyError, e:` was 2.7 specific but that is the limit of my knowledge

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, i ran it with 2.7 and it works. The problem just is that i want the code to keep calculating the other distance despite the ones there is no information about. how i can ask python to keep on running? Beacuase even with the code pass , it just stops there

Comment: This is what the code should be doing right now. If i understand you are calculating 1 distance per row? If that is the case, python will execute what is in the `try` statement. If a KeyError exception is raise, it will execute the `except`statement. The `pass` keyword here means 'Do nothing' but keep looping. Therefore it will ignore the current row and move on to the next one.

Comment: well that is very odd. If you have a print statement in the except, pass isn't even necessary by the way. Are you sure the try, except block is in the for loop?

Comment: you are right. i had that wrong. But now I have the problem that python doesnt save the "nonexisting result" for the itineraires that are missing in the csv file, and it stops running when it arrives to another itineraire that doesnt exist. So in the end, I only have data on the csv file for the itineraires before the first error.

Comment: well python doesn't save non existing result because you don't tell it to do so :). As for why it stops on the next that doesn't exist, that is weird. If you wanna store non existing result that add a line of code in the `except` that writes a line to your csv file with whatever you want in there. As for the rest unless you update your question with the current code and maybe a small sample csv output/input file I can't help further